# I'm getting a 401 while calling the wp-json endpoint via ajax

Tags: ajax

**N.B. Resolved - I hadn't noticed it was a POST rather than a GET.**

I'm trying to use an AJAX call from a front end page to pull a list "Staff" (custom post type). I can get the data in the browser via wp-json/wp/v2/staff but I get a 401 when I try to pull the data via AJAX. I'm assuming I need to authenticate somehow but can't work out how to to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: All those docs talk about making changes on the PHP side. Surely that's not required!?

Comment: Depending on what you’re trying to do, yes it is. Normally custom post type endpoints don’t require authentication, but if that’s been added then you need to follow those steps to ensure your request is authenticated.

Comment: I can explore all the data I need by just going to the wp-jason url I posted above. I could probably scrape it which seems utterly ridiculous. But I can’t get it via Ajax. Something is wrong with that.

Comment: There’s something wrong with your AJAX request then. But there’s no code in your question so it’s not possible to say more. It sounds like you might be sending a POST request instead of GET.

Comment: Fair point. I’ll post the code. It’s a ‘get’ request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you everyone for looking at this but I made a dumb error. Been starting at it too long to spot. It was a post rather than a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accidentally created a POST rather than a GET. Obviously, you need credentials if you post.